# Unable to join the domain with Windows 7 professional

Tags: windows-7, domain

I've just received a new laptop with a ghosted Windows 7 Professional image. When I go join the machine to the domain I see the 'Domain' text box greyed out (the system is in Spanish) :

[image: Join domain dialogue box]

My local account has administrator rights. To verify it's not my account that's at fault I've enabled the Administrator account and tried to join, logging in with that account, without any success. Does anyone know why that box is greyed out? The 'Network ID' button is also greyed out in the system properties dialogue box.

Comment: Make sure your WIndows 7 in not HOME edition.
It should be at least PRO

Comment: It was the Pro edition. In the end a re-install from DVD sorted out the problem.

Comment: Check that the WORKSTATION service is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that there was something wrong with the image used to ghost the machine from. A re-install from scratch using the DVD resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Device Manager and make sure the network card is ok.

Also check to make sure the correct protocols are installed. Right Click the NIC and choose properties.  "Client for Microsoft Network" etc should all be there.

You also want to check your Services.  Computer Browser, WorkStation, Netlogon, etc should be running.

Comment: Starting the Net Login services gives the following in the event log - "This computer is configured as a member of a workgroup, not as a member of a domain. The Netlogon service does not need to run in this configuration.". All the other services you mention are started and the adapters (Wifi and ethernet) have the MS client installed.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I thought for sure the "Computer Browsing Service" would be the culprit. Or even "Client for Microsoft Network". I would try unpluging the computer from the network and reboot, see if that will help. If not try changing the computer name. Some more things you could try:

Removing all [instances of "WORKGROUP"](http://www.certforums.co.uk/forums/networks/15864-change-domain-greyed-out.html) from the registry

Seeing if there is some kind of [hidden GPO preventing change](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/systemcenterdeployment/thread/9b8674e4-6532-48af-ac29-9c09df869582)

If none of that works, well poop, we'll have to find something outlandish to try! Good luck!

Comment: Changing the name had no effect, neither did removing references to "WORKGROUP" in the registry. I'll take a look at downloading the GPO tools to see if that sees anything. I have a suspicion that whoever built the ghost image has done something strange. Perhaps I'll need to rebuild from scratch.

Comment: Yeah, if you can't find the source of the issue, and it's an uncommon one, you might just have to. I had a server one time that would NOT install AD. No matter what I tried. Spent three weeks to no avail. Reinstalled the OS and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade it to home and then upgrade it to pro again using the windows anytime upgrade.Make sure you have the anytime upgrade keys.
I just did mine and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I know that this topic is old but I just found the way to fix it without formating the pc.

I've tryed every tip available on internet but it just doesnt works, so my last try was to unninstal the service pack 1, and that did the trick.

You just have to locate the kb and unninstal.

I hope this helps anyone that have this same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Steps to try:

1. Do you have the correct DNS settings (the primary server should be a Windows AD DNS server).
2. Is "Client for Microsoft Networks" listed on the network adapter properties?
3. If you have access to the AD, add your computer first, then see if it lets you join.

Comment: 1. appears to be ok 2. Yes it's there for both adapters 3. I don't have direct access to the PDC

Comment: This has nothing to do with the DC.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem with Windows 7 Enterprise, and it was resolved by generating a new SID and changing the name of the PC to something new (I used [NewSID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897418) for that).

Comment: Do not use the tool NewSID it will destroy your windows installation and you wont be able to boot the system after you used the tool.