# Cannot change my network id or domain name On win 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-name

Im logged in as a local administrator on a machine part of a workgroup and find that Under the "computer name" tab in system properties, the option to click the "change" button or "network id" is greyed out and therefore cant change the workgroup name or add this machine to a domain.

Im running win 7 Enterprise service pack 1.

PS :workstation service already activated .
[network id" is greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H03CG.jpg)
[cant chnage the domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBlKU.jpg)

Comment: Questions: Is the network type "Work"? Was this computer in the past on a domain? Is Client for Microsoft Networks installed? Does it work when booting to Safe Mode with Networking?

Comment: possible duplicate https://superuser.com/questions/334933/unable-to-join-the-domain-with-windows-7-professional

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, we need to check whether the Workstation service is started. To do this, we can go to Start menu > Run services.msc and scroll down the list to Workstation service  and change Startup type to automatic.

Hope the information can be helpful.

Best regards,
Lavilian